# Can Sharepoint store small audio and video files

Tags: sharepoint

I work in an international school with a variety of difficult to pronounce first and last names. I would like to set up a visual phonetic database, but also have the students each record their voice saying their first and last name.

I would also like to link this (list I think it's called in Sharepoint) with a webpage, so a Principal, when reading off names at an awards gathering, could correctly say them.

Is this all possible within Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You could use insert Video and Audio with OOB function, check official guideline [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-video-audio-or-images-to-a-classic-page-b5220c61-e56a-40fd-8754-d06a2e38b492).